# Invalid maximum heap size error in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, linux, android-studio

I'm using latest version of android studio in Ubuntu(linux). After make changes to vm options. I'm unable to run android studio.
I'm getting this error while starting android studio -

```
Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx4096m # <------ increase this to most of your RAM
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

`This is my studio64.vmoptions file :`

```
-Xms256m
-Xmx1280m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-XX:CICompilerCount=2
-Dsun.io.useCanonPrefixCache=false
-Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""
-Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true
-Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug=off
-Djdk.module.illegalAccess.silent=true
-Djna.nosys=true
-Djna.boot.library.path=
-Didea.vendor.name=Google
-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd
-Dsun.java2d.renderer=sun.java2d.marlin.MarlinRenderingEngine
-Dsun.tools.attach.tmp.only=true
```

How to fix it? I'm Also tried to delete studio64.vmoptions and studio.vmoptions files. But issue still going on.

Comment: i'm using 64bit

Comment: And ram is 4gb.

Answer (score 4):

`Thank you so much for myself`. I got it in 2 hours. After searching too much on google, `found nothing` that works for me.

*This is the only way to solve it.*

**Note : I'm using Ubuntu with 4g ram 64bit**

**Step 1.** Go to file manager > show hidden files

**Step 2.** Go to folder > .config/Google/AndroidStudio-versionName

**Step 3.** Delete studio64.vmoptions file

**Step 4.** Restart Android Studio

Comment: Big thanks! There's so many bloody config files and I don't know how I would have found it without your help.